# How to homogenize components size in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager

I have a JTable with two columns. The first one contains a custom component (bargraph) with three components inside it:  JLabel lMinLabel, Graph lGraph and JLabel lMaxLabel. Here is what I have:

[image]

Here is what I want:
[image]

The values label can have different sizes in the different rows, which modify the size of the bargraph. I want the bargraph to have the same size for all JTable rows.

I tryed to put the label in panels, and set a minimum size to these panels (with a fixed value).

Here is my code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class JTableExample extends JFrame {

    public JTableExample() {
        super("JTable Example");

        DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
        dm.setDataVector(new Object[][] { { new BarGraph(0, 10, 25, 27, 75, 90,100), "foo" },
            { new BarGraph(100, 1000, 2500, 5600, 7500, 9000,10000), "bar" } },
                new Object[] { "Graph", "String" });

        JTable table = new JTable(dm);
        table.getColumn("Graph").setCellRenderer(new Renderer());
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scroll);
        setSize(800, 100);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTableExample frame = new JTableExample();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}

class Renderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    public Renderer() {}
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        return (Component) value;
    }
}
```

The bargraph class where I try to set the standard size:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BarGraph extends JComponent {


    private final double preWarningMax;
    private final double preWarningMin;
    private final double valueMax;
    private final double valueMin;
    private final double warningMax;
    private final double warningMin;
    private double value;

    public BarGraph(double pValueMin, double pWarningMin, double pPreWarningMin, double pValue, double pPreWarningMax,
            double pWarningMax, double pValueMax) {
        super();
        valueMin = pValueMin;
        warningMin = pWarningMin;
        preWarningMin = pPreWarningMin;
        value = pValue;
        preWarningMax = pPreWarningMin;
        warningMax = pWarningMax;
        valueMax = pValueMax;
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        JPanel lMinPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel lMinValue = new JLabel(Double.toString(valueMin));
        lMinPanel.add(lMinValue);

        Graph lGraph = new Graph();

        JPanel lMaxPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel lMaxValue = new JLabel(Double.toString(valueMax));
        lMaxPanel.add(lMaxValue);

        add(lMinPanel);
        add(lGraph);
        add(lMaxPanel);

        lMinPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(15, 5));
        lMaxPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(15, 5));
    }

    private class Graph extends JComponent {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics pGraphics) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to homogenize the bargraph size betweens the JTable rows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JPanel lMinPanel = new JPanel();
JLabel lMinValue = new JLabel(Double.toString(valueMin));
lMinPanel.add(lMinValue);
```

Why are you creating an extra panel to hold each JLabel?

Notice how the text is below the top of the cell. That is because the default FlowLayout of the panel adds 5 pixels around all edges of the panel.

Get rid of the panel and just add the JLabel directly to panel with the BoxLayout.

> The bargraph class where I try to set the standard size:

```
    lMinPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(15, 5));
    lMaxPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(15, 5));
```

The problem is the `BoxLayout` respects the "maximum" size. So all components will grow to fill the space available.

Instead, I think you want to set the maximum size. So using my first suggestion the basic code should be something like:

```
lMinValue.setMaximumSize( new Dimension(50, lminValue.getPreferredSize().height) );
```

You would also set this for the lMaxValue.

Then you add lMinValue/lMaxValue to the component.

You would leave the max size of the chart panel alone, so it should then grow to take all the space after the 100 pixels have been allocated to the two labels.

Note, this assumes the maximum size of the bar chart is greater than its preferred size.

Comment: I set a JPanel because I thought I couldn't resize the JLabel and that would be possible if I tryed to resize a JPanel. But you are right, the label are sufficient. I tryed your solution, the bargraph were still not equals, but by using setPreferredSize instead of setMaximumSize, it worked ! the solution is to write: lMinValue.setPreferedSize( new Dimension(50, lminValue.getPreferredSize().height) );

Comment: *the bargraph were still not equals,* - did you verify if the preferred size and maximum size of the bargraph is the same? If so, the I would suggest you set the maximum size to some value greater, which will allow the bargrapgh to grow/shrink if the column width is ever changed by the user.